# How back to the certain point inside endless loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have problem with installation of goto, but also I'm not really sure if I want use it in my code, so if inside while true endless cycle I want back to the certain  point  with condition somewhere below inside main loop too, how to figure out with it in python?

here is a structure which is inside while true endless loop and good if I can get it without goto

```
x = 0

#some code

a + b # just some place in code, which must be return point if further condition is true

if x > 0: # if x is not 0 make it 0
     x = (x == 0)

#some code

if y == 1: # some result to make further condition true
     x = (x + 1)

if x == 1:        
    # and here if I have this condition from above go to a + b and start from there

#some code
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. But there is no `goto` in standard python. Did you mean `turtle.goto`? Or perhaps the [`goto`](http://entrian.com/goto/) module?

Comment: yes goto module, but I have problem with installation, maybe somehow without goto, I've edited the post to show what I want

Answer (score 2):

You can get that behavior with `while True` plus `continue` and `break`. No module required.

```
x = 0

#some code

while True:

    a + b # just some place in code, which must be return point if further condition is true

    if x > 0: # if x is not 0 make it 0
        x = (x == 0)

    #some code

    if y == 1: # some result to make further condition true
        x = (x + 1)

    if x == 1:        
        # and here if I have this condition from above go to a + b and start from there
        continue
    break

#some code
```

**EDIT: With functions**

```
def other_function():
    a = 1
    while True:
        # some code
        if a == b:
            continue
        # some more code
        if sin(a) < sqrt(a**2 + b**2):
            break:
        # more code
    # still more code

def main():
    # some code
    while True:
        # some more code
        other_function()
        # still more code
    # after a while
    exit(0)
```

Comment: hello, I have try blocks with exception  inside this while true if I go this way. everything is inside main while true endless loop, so selected parts of code works exactly this way with break and continue, more precisely between blocks, but in certain  places  is difficult to use it  this way now

Comment: Then put parts of your code that belong together out into separate functions to structure your code better. You can also put the remainder of the loop inside an if-clause and only run it if your goto-condition is not true.

Comment: can you show me please some simple example with function for this case